# How to get grouping result as a list from the enumerable list?

Tags: c#, enumerable

How do I get unique records from list?

```
public class VinDecoded
{
    public string SquishVin {get;set;} = "";
    public string Year {get;set;} = "";
    public string Make {get;set;} = "";
}
var modelVinDecodeds = new List<VinDecoded>();

modelVinDecodeds.Add(new VinDecoded() {SquishVin="1234",Year="2007",Make="Ford"});
modelVinDecodeds.Add(new VinDecoded() {SquishVin="2233",Year="2010",Make="Chevy"});
modelVinDecodeds.Add(new VinDecoded() {SquishVin="2233",Year="2010",Make="GMC"});
```

In this case, I want to get custom `List<VinDecoded>()` having only the matching SquishVin of "2233".

This I tried which don't work.  I'm getting Key and no List.  I only want the `List<VinDecoded>()` data where there's no List.

```
var modelCustomVinDecoded = modelVinDecodeds.GroupBy(x => x.SquishVin).ToList();

foreach(var v in modelCustomVinDecoded)
{
    if (v.Key != "0033")
    {
         FooSave(v.???);   //Where's the list coming from the v part?
    }
}
```

Comment: you want group by in linq its correct?

Comment: or you need to get "2233" result only mean, use where condition

Comment: I updated an better example above, see if that help.

Comment: v in foreach(var v in modelCustomVinDecoded) is IEnumerable<VinDecoded>, so you can iterate or convert it to a list v.ToList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupBy(x => x.SquishVin)` will returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, VinDecoded>>` and `IGrouping<string, VinDecoded>` have a property called Key returning the `SquishVin` in all `VinDecoded` objects in the group. Also `IGrouping<string, VinDecoded>` is an `IEnumerable<VinDecode>`, so you can iterate it or just convert it to a list.

You can do this:

```
var modelCustomVinDecoded = modelVinDecodeds.GroupBy(x => x.SquishVin).ToList();

foreach(var v in modelCustomVinDecoded)
{
    if (v.Key != "0033")
    {
        FooSave(v.ToList());
    }
}
```